# "Your browser is being managed by your organization" for home/personal installation of firefox

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I get this message on `about:preferences` on Firefox 103.0. Why?

[image: screenshot.]

Clicking on it doesn't seem to give me any information that I can understand:

[image: Screenshot of about:policies.]

Searching online, I find there's a "Firefox for Enterprise" but it shouldn't be the one that's installed, I've installed firefox from `apt` default repository on ubuntu 22.04 on my personal computer (I've installed the OS, I'm the only superuser).

How can I know:

1. If I'm running Firefox Enterprise edition or regular edition?
2. Who's the organization controlling my browser?
3. What access do they have to my browser, browsing activity, etc?
4. How could this have happened?

Comment: Do you have anything in the `about:policies` page?

Comment: As noted, check all the policies governing Firefox. On my Ubuntu 22.04 machine, Firefox is not managed. On my Kali machine, Kali manages it and puts it dark mode. Intolerable. I dumped Firefox on Kali and wen to Chrome and now also use Chrome on Ubuntu.

Comment: Added contents of `about:policies` to the question, I can also add what I see after clicking on "documentation". However, I don't understand either of them.

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but Ubuntu does not always keep Firefox up-to-date (and hardly *ever* updates Thunderbird!), so you might try updating from Mozilla directly: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/mozilla_team_thunderbird_stable and https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/firefox_aurora or https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/mozilla_team_firefox_next. If Firefox was installed in SNAP, remove that installation, first.